# Forge tool handleButtonDown and handleButtonUp functions not getting called

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I was looking at the sample code for the tutorial at https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-part-iii which is located at https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.SelectionWindow/Viewing.Extension.SelectionWindow.Tool.js as well as the documentation at https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/toolinterface/ --- Most of these functions are getting called properly in my tool such as handleSingleClick, handleMouseMove, handleKeyDown, and so on, but two of them are not getting hit -- handleButtonDown and handleButtonUp. I was using viewer version 3.3.x but I have updated to use 4.0.x thinking that that might help to resolve the problem, but the same issue occurs in both versions. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code block from the`Autodesk.Viewing.ToolController#__invokeStack()`, `_toolStack` stands for activated tools in the `ToolController`, the `method` stands for callback functions started with `handle`, i.e. handleSingleClick, handleMouseMove, handleKeyDown, handleButtonDown, handleButtonUp, etc.

```
for( var n = _toolStack.length;  --n >= 0;  )
{
    var tool = _toolStack[n];

    if( tool[method] && tool[method](arg1, arg2) )
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Based on my experience, if there is a handle function such as `handleButtonDown` or `handleButtonUp` executed before your custom tools' and returned true, then your handles will never be called.

Fortunately, Forge Viewer (v3.2) starts invoking a priority mechanism for custom tools registered in `ToolController`. `ToolController` will use the priority number to sort the tools in it, and the priority number of each tool is 0 by default. You can override the priority to make your tools be hit before other tools like this way,  to add a function `getPriority()` to return a number greater than 0:

```
this.getPriority = function() {
   return 100;
};
```

Comment: Thank you doing the .getPriority suggestion seems to work

Answer (score 1):

I found out that when using ES6 and the `class` syntax, extending your tool from `Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface` will prevent the overrides to work properly, probably because it is not implemented using `prototype` in the viewer source code.

You can simply create a class and implement the methods that are of interest for your tool:

```
// KO: not working! 
class MyTool extends Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface {

     getName () {
         return 'MyTool'
     } 

     getNames () {

         return ['MyTool']
     }   

     handleButtonDown (event, button) {

         return false
     }
}

// OK 
class MyTool {

     getName () {
         return 'MyTool'
     } 

     getNames () {

         return ['MyTool']
     }    

     handleButtonDown (event, button) {

         return false
     }
}
```